# GPS Locater not working

Tags: android

Im trying to get the current user location via GPS. I've read the google documents on this and have tried a few tutorials but nothing seems to work properly. Here is my code:

```
public class useGPS extends Activity implements LocationListener
{
private static final String TAG = "useGPS:";
LocationManager myLocManager;
TextView locationData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.use_gps );

    myLocManager = ( LocationManager )this.getSystemService( LOCATION_SERVICE );
    Location location = myLocManager.getLastKnownLocation( myLocManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ;
    if( location != null )
    {
        Log.d( TAG,location.toString() );
        Toast.makeText( this, "Location changed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        this.onLocationChanged( location );
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    myLocManager.requestLocationUpdates( myLocManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, this );

}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    myLocManager.removeUpdates( this );
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    Log.d( TAG,"onLocationChanged with location: "+location.toString() );

    // Return a string representation of the latitude & longitude. Pass it to the textview and update the text
    String text = "Lat: "+location.getLatitude()+"\nLong: "+location.getLongitude();

    locationData = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.locationData );
    locationData.setText( text );
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Provider Disabled...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Provider Enabled...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I'm aware that GPS tends to not work indoors so I went and stood outside for 5minutes and it didn't make a difference. When I used the emulator to simulate a location it returned the lat & long of the location fine - no errors.

Also - I have included the necessary permissions in the manifest file as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Any idea's as to why this isn't working?

Comment: have you checked with e.g. google maps or some GPS test tool, that you really get a location from GPS? It could take really long on some devices. You may even have GPS disabled.

Comment: Define really long - I've been staring at the device for 15 minutes and its not doing anything besides the satellite image at the top of the screen animating - you know the whole satellite-sending-signal thing...

Comment: GPS has no location until the GPS icon stops blinking. Depending on your location / satellite visibility / assistance data availability etc long = 30 minutes or so.

Comment: or maybe just 15 minutes if you don't miss the almanac data because of bad GPS signal strengh: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_fix

Comment: It's common for the process to take some time to get all the ephermis data / almanac from satellites if you're using GPS only (although, it should not be longer than couple of minutes). Have you tried turning on internet connection (so it could fetch some of the data it needs from time servers)?

Comment: try giving all GPS related permissions that includes course location as well

Comment: The manifest file also has internet permission so this shouldn't be a problem. I ran google maps on the phone and it's out by I'd say 500 metres or so. I'm certainly not willing to have the app open for 30minutes just to get an initial location - that isn't realistic. I'll add in the COARSE location permission too - though it shouldn't make a difference at all...

Comment: I added a whole list of new permissions to try to ensure that all bases have been covered but to no avail: fine & coarse location, internet, location_extra_commands, access_mock_location & control_location_updates. I also changed the LocationMangager to get NETWORK_PROVIDER updates, not GPS but still I receive nothing. The app has been running for 10 minutes now but still nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I fixed the problem - I decided to tweak the code to create the listener instead of implementing it in the class. I also ensured that I called both the NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER on the requestLocationUpdates to cover both bases. Here is the revised code, please note that the commented out geocoding part crashes the program for the moment, I haven't worked out the bugs yet...

```
public class useGPS extends Activity
{
private static final String TAG = "useGPS:";

TextView locationData, addressData;
LocationManager myLocManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.use_gps );

    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    myLocManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    locationListener = new LocationListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {
            // Return a string representation of the latitude & longitude. Pass it to the textview and update the text
            String text = "Lat: "+location.getLatitude()+"\nLong: "+location.getLongitude();

            locationData = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.locationData );
            locationData.setText( text );
            /**
            try
            {
                // Reverse Geocoding
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder( getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault() );
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation( location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(),0 );

                if( addresses != null )
                {
                    // Get return address data
                    Address returnedAddress = addresses.get( 0 );
                    StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder( "Address:\n" );

                    for( int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++ )
                    {
                        // Return the address
                        strReturnedAddress.append( returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i) ).append( "\n" );
                    }
                    // Set our textview to the address returned
                    addressData.setText( strReturnedAddress.toString() );
                } else {
                    addressData.setText( "Sorry, no address returned..." );
                }

            } catch( IOException e )
            {
                // Catch the Exception
                e.printStackTrace();
                addressData.setText( "Error: Cannot get Address!" );
            }
            */
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
        {

        }

    };

    // The two lines below request location updates from both GPS & the network location provider
    myLocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener );
    myLocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener );
}

@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    // The two lines below request location updates from both GPS & the network location provider
    myLocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener );
    myLocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener );
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    // The two lines below request location updates from both GPS & the network location provider
    myLocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener );
    myLocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener );
}

}
```

One final point - I'm not sure as of this moment whether I need the two requestLocationUpdate methods on the onResume() and onPause() methods. The onResume() method will probably be changed to get the last known location, if there is one, instead of re-establishing the location updates method.

Hope this helps others...